# AndroidX and Support Library Conflict: Duplicate class errors

Tags: android, mobile-development

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> C:\Users\UC\StudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\java\com\sadaqaworks\quranprojects\fragment\AyahWordFragment.java:70: error: incompatible types: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
> fastScroller.setRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
> ^
> C:\Users\UC\StudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\java\com\sadaqaworks\quranprojects\fragment\AyahWordFragment.java:73: error: incompatible types: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener cannot be converted to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
> mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(fastScroller.getOnScrollListener());
> ^
> C:\Users\UC\StudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\java\com\sadaqaworks\quranprojects\fragment\AyahWordFragment.java:96: error: incompatible types: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
> recyclerViewHeader.attachTo(mRecyclerView, true);
> ^
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
> 3 errors

Duplicate class found
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0)

gradle:
dependencies {

```
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02")
implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0")
implementation("com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1")
implementation("com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader:library:1.2.0")
implementation("xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3")

testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
```

}

CODE:
@Override
public View onCreateView(
LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ayah_word, container, false);

```
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_ayah_word_view);

// for fast scroll
VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller fastScroller = view.findViewById(R.id.fast_scroller);

// Connect the recycler to the scroller (to let the scroller scroll the list)
fastScroller.setRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

// Connect the scroller to the recycler (to let the recycler scroll the scroller's handle)
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(fastScroller.getOnScrollListener());

ayahWordAdapter = new AyahWordAdapter(ayahWordArrayList, getActivity(), surah_id);

return view;
```

}

I have tried to shift all to androidx but idk here the error lies, is the error coming from the third party library im using, is it just corrupted or what lol

Comment: Looks like the third party library hasn't supported androidx yet. Just check their code on github to findout

Comment: Why you have two different version of `material` library included at the same time?

Comment: moreover you are using 9 years old library in your project ... which isn't compatible with modern libraries

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.